# install zip files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I have downloaded PyCharm and unzipped using `unzip` command .

by using helps on internet , i have a problem with `./configure` command :

`ash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you in the correct dir when running the ./configure?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `chmod +x name-here.sh` then `./configure` or `sh configure` or `sh configure.sh`? Also you may try to use `sudo sh configure`. When I have problems I try all.

Comment: i try them but again Errors!! I start downloading by Ubuntu software

Comment: @Mohammadjavad If the app is available in as an apt or deb inside the ubuntu software store you should always install that one instead.